# Shovel operator (<<) returning nil for instance's id in a many-to-many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, has-many-through, join

I'm following the RailsGuides [**tutorial**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) in an attempt to understand associations with join tables.

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end
```

I assign my model instances as so:

```
patient     = Patient.first
physician   = Physician.first
appointment = Appointment.first

appointment.patient   = patient
appointment.physician = physician
```

While experimenting in the rails console I noticed that adding appointments to either patients or physicians using `.push()` works as expected.

```
patient.appointments.push(appointment)
=> #<Appointment id: 1, physician_id: 1, patient_id: 1, appointment_date: nil, created_at: "2015-06-18 13:45:19", updated_at: "2015-06-18 13:47:30">
```

But if I were to use the shovel operator to append the appointment the `physician_id` isn't saved:

```
patient.appointments << appointment
[#<Appointment id: 1, physician_id: nil, patient_id: 1, appointment_date: nil, created_at: "2015-06-18 13:45:19", updated_at: "2015-06-18 13:46:58">, #<Appointment id: 1, physician_id: 1, patient_id: 1, appointment_date: nil, created_at: "2015-06-18 13:45:19", updated_at: "2015-06-18 13:47:30">]
```

Why does it appear to be a different appointment instance with no physician_id despite there being one?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your problem is, but note that if you do this `appointment.patient   = patient` and don't proceed to save `appointment` then you won't make any changes to the database, unlike `<<` which DOES make changes.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the "<<" operator.   The appointment never has it's physician set prior to adding it to the patient's appointments

Comment: @MaxWilliams but for active record `push` is simply aliased to `<<` [source - line 967](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb) so it should work the same way for both shouldn't it?

Comment: `push` seems to return the element pushed into the array, `<<` seems to return the whole array. In your example it seems that the `patient.appointments` returns twice the same result (appointment id #1), maybe you should investigate on this

Comment: I don't know whether `push` is meant to be an alias for `<<` (or vice versa).  It looks like one is returning a single object and the other an array, and also that one is using the object in memory while the other is using the object reloaded from the database. Like i said earlier, you haven't saved `appointment` after changing it's patient_id so it's probably best to do that before using `push` or `<<`.

Comment: Aha, @MrYoshiji has noticed the key to the issue i think.  It looks like you'd already added the existing appointment object to `patient.appointments`, then you modify appointment and push it into patient.appointments **again**.  So now it's in there **twice**:  the one in the database (which doesn't have physician id) and the one in memory (which does have the physician id).

Comment: @MaxWilliams Yeah it seems to be a database/memory issue. Created new appointment, patient, and physician instances and it seemed to work. Thanks.